# Getting the text from a Chip

Tags: android, androidx

The official docs [recommend](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip.html#getChipText()) setting the text for a `Chip` via `.setChipText()` and to retrieve the text using `getText()`. However, the said method will always return an empty string unless we also set the text using `.setText()`. This poses an issue since that method is not properly supported and overflows outside of the `Chip` bounds.
How else may I retrieve the text from `Chip`?

One hacky solution I'm using right now is it make the `.setText()` text transparent: `.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip#setchiptext) you provided:

> setChipText 
> void setChipText (CharSequence chipText) 
>   This method is deprecated. 
>   Use setText(CharSequence) instead.